# Force required field on second registration step with devise and on-update callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a User model which uses Devise for authentication. My User model has additional attributes like city etc.

On my registration page i only require email and password on user creation. Then i redirect the user to the User edit page to fill up the additional fields.

Validation looks like this:

```
validates :email, :password, presence: true
validates :city, presence: true, on: :update
```

So far so good - everything works fine with Rails 5.0.2 - now i upgraded to 5.1.5 and it redirects me straight back to registration page with the message 'city required'.. in the console i can see that the User is created. The thing is - it updates the user on login with last signed in stuff.

It's weird cause it shouldn't work with either of those rails versions.

Is there any better solution to force the user to update some additional fields after registration?

My registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out some kind of 'hack' to easily get it working:

```
validates :city, presence: true, unless: lambda { |u| u.last_sign_in_at_was.nil? }
```

The **_was** part is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Your `on: update` must be within the options for the presence-validation. eg:

```
validates :city, presence: { on: :update }
```

However - you could also consider looking into using a form-pattern for each step of your process... which is how a lot of people do multi-stage form validation. Each form represents a stage in the process and has its own set of validations.

Comment: nope the on update changes nothing. it also seems that its correct: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on